# Swap 2 objects, without using a temporary variable

Tags: code-challenge

There are two objects:

```
Object1, Object2
```

You can easily swap them by:

```
Object3 = Object1
Object1 = Object2
Object2 = Object3
```

However, you must solve this problem by using no temporary object and Object1 should be changed to Object 2. (and vice versa)

Comment: Here we have a prime example of [what is wrong with challenges that don't have "an objective winning criteria"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/564/should-we-consider-dropping-or-modifying-the-objective-winning-criteria-requir) as currently required by the FAQ: three different answer that are all *completely correct*. So how will people judge them? All that we have here is a popularity context.

Comment: @dmckee, the problem here isn't lack of objective winning criteria, but of any winning criteria.

Comment: Would this count in Python? `a,b=b,a`

Answer (score 4):

### Python

I'll say it first.

```
object1, object2 = object2, object1
```

Comment: Also possible in Go. However, I think a temporary variable may still be made in the compiled code.

Comment: This is also valid Ruby.

Comment: @MaxMorin: Python-the-language-spec describes this as creating an anonymous tuple of the objects on the right, then unpacking to the names on the left. CPython-the-reference-interpreter skips the actual `tuple` (it just loads the two objects onto the stack, swaps the top two stack entries, then unpacks).

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the memory address of these objects, you can swap them by xor-ing their addresses.

```
// return 0 for success, 1 for error
int swap(void *object1, void *object2, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        char *x = (char *)(object1 + i);
        char *y = (char *)(object2 + i);
        if (x == y)
            return 1;
        *x ^= *y;
        *y ^= *x;
        *x ^= *y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

per dmckee suggestion for clarity

Comment: The solution is to pass a size as well, cast to `char*` and then xor swap the characters guarding against the same-value failure mode. Not as pretty, but standards compliant and working.

Comment: Only answer which doesn't do `a,b = b,a`. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica

A standard feature:

```
a = 1; b = 2;
Print[a, " ", b];
{a, b} = {b, a};
Print[a, " ", b];
```

Output

```
(*
1 2

2 1
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**PostScript**

In PostScript, it's common to use the stack instead of named variables, so a simple

```
exch
```

would do the job. But if you have variables, you can do it like

```
/a 1 def
/b 2 def
/a b /b a def def
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

```
($object1, $object2) = ($object2, $object1);
```

Using Perl's list assertions feels like cheating, but it's a pretty common feature.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

Objects / arrays / resources:

```
list($a, $b) = [$b, $a];
```

Integers / booleans / strings of equal length:

```
$a ^= $b ^= $a ^= $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Forth

```
swap
```

As i have to include more than 30 characters, here's a link to a [Forth primer](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/primer.htm)